# Simple function reverts without error message

Tags: solidity

This function simply transfers an amount of tokens to the contract and stores values based on a staking tier, why would it revert with no error message?
All my revert and require statements provide a message.
I tried in remix using Javascript VM, it said the function needs to be 'payable', which I thought didn't make sense as it is only transferring tokens. I tried a 'payable' version of the function and it still fails.
Any idea where the issue in the code could be?

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x503bbf6d4a84cad0698c31d20c9522215d95e5fbe051d72e4c079b851358753d

```
function StakeTokens(uint256 amount, uint256 dayLength)
    public
{
    require(amount > 0, "Stake amount can not be 0");
    require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount, "Error: insufficient balance");
    
    Staked memory userStake = staked[msg.sender];

    if(dayLength == 0){
        if(token0StakedBalances[msg.sender] == 0){
            total0stakeholders++; 
        }
        token0StakedBalances[msg.sender] += amount;
        total0Staked += amount;
        userStake.Stake0StartTimestamp = block.timestamp;
    }
    else if(dayLength == 180){
        if(token180StakedBalances[msg.sender] == 0){
            total180stakeholders++;
        }
        token180StakedBalances[msg.sender] += amount;
        total180Staked += amount;
        userStake.Stake180StartTimestamp = block.timestamp;
    }
    else if(dayLength == 270){
        if(token270StakedBalances[msg.sender] == 0){
            total270stakeholders++;
        }
        token270StakedBalances[msg.sender] += amount;
        total270Staked += amount;
        userStake.Stake270StartTimestamp = block.timestamp;
    }
    else if(dayLength == 365){
        if(token365StakedBalances[msg.sender] == 0){
            total365stakeholders++;
        }
        token365StakedBalances[msg.sender] += amount;
        total365Staked += amount;
        userStake.Stake365StartTimestamp = block.timestamp;
    }
    else{
        revert("Invalid stake length");
    }

    totalStaked = totalStaked.add(amount);
    staked[msg.sender] = userStake;

    require(token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= amount, 
        "Please first approve");
    require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount),
            "Transfer failed");  

    emit TokenStake(msg.sender, amount, dayLength);
   
}
```

Comment: do a `debug.traceTransaction()`, there will be `returnValue` in the output. Decode the string with a hex decoder, it will show you the revert error string, if solidity compiler was instructed to produce error code strings during compilation time. You can only debug transactions not past last 128 blocks since state is kept in memory only.

Comment: check for allowance , this is the most common error